# virtualbox ubuntu network set

Tags: interface, subnet

I am kind of new to Ubuntu and networking. I am trying to create on a VM (which is set on NAT network) to create two subnetworks. I tried to create on /etc/network/interfaces two new interfaces eth1 and eth2. 
[sample of my intefaces file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkMOf.png)

What's the correct way to create two subnetworks on a VM ?

Comment: Which VM software are you using? Is Ubuntu the host or guest(s)? (or both?)

Comment: I am using Oracle VM VirtuaBox and Ubuntu is host

Comment: You set up the subnets in the host Vbox (application) settings, not the host OS network settings. Vbox will do the rest for you. Undo all manual changes to your interfaces file. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html